# Pandas fails to convert object to string or int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
| date     | spot           |
| -------- | -------------- |
|date1     |   4 283        |
| date2    |   4 198        |
```

Note that there is a space before and after the thousand's digit.
When I did `print(df.dtypes)`, it shows the df['spot'] is of object type.

To remove the spaces, I wanted to first convert the object to string, remove the spaces in the string, and then convert the string to int.

```
df['spot'] = df['spot'].astype(str)
df['spot'] = df['spot'].str.strip()
df['spot'] = df['spot'].astype(int)
```

But the object was not converted to string or int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace the space in the middle of the number first.

```
df['spot'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)

1    4283
2    4198
Name: spot, dtype: int32
```

---

the error for the `.astype` call is quite clear.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 283'
```

`4 283` will be a viewed as a literal string and not an integer.

a better method would be to use the `thousands` argument in `read_csv`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

d = """ date|spot
date1    |   4 283        
date2    |   4 198"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='|',thousands=' ')

print(df['spot'])

0    4283
1    4198
Name: spot, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! When I googled on stackoverflow, all the suggestions for converting data types were .astype(). Why does it not work even when I did astype(str)??

Comment: No, I did astype(str) first and it didn't even change object to string.

Comment: @minerva_ace `object` in pandas is a string type

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove that extra space:

```
df.spot =  df.spot.str.replace(' ', '').astype(int)
```

And if you need to extract the 2nd int value after `' '` use:

```
df.spot = df.spot.str.strip().str.split(' ').str[1].astype(int)
```